# Disable Chrome session restore popup

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to permanently disable the Google Chrome session restore (see screenshot)?

It appears at almost every system start. Not everytime, which makes it difficult to reproduce. Also, I could not notice any relation to whether there was a previous crash or not.

[image]

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Sorry, could you please elaborate. Not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean delete all settings and starting up like after a fresh install?